# Having mixed results using Separate

Tags: modeling, objects

I'm trying out a bit of a different modeling work flow.

Following along with the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jO9grYSFx0M#t=6m

I'm curious what extra is happening here with/or before using Separate.

My result:
[image: object in blender]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is move the mirror modifier above the subsurf modifier using the little arrows at the top tight of the modifiers.